# In a VAR model, why are white noises correlated with each other in the reduced form model

Tags: time-series, covariance-matrix, vector-autoregression, white-noise

With my understanding, we have 2 different models when studying VAR processes (Vector Autoregression).

We have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} y_{t} \\ x_{t} \end{bmatrix}  =  \begin{bmatrix} c_{1,0} \\ c_{2,0} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} b_{11,1} & b_{12,1} \\ b_{21,1} & b_{22,1} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_{t-1} \\ x_{t-1} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} u_{y,t} \\ u_{x,t} \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
which is known as the reduced form model which does not allow for contemporaneous feedback between y and x and has the covariance matrix $\Sigma_{u} = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{y}^{2} &\sigma_{yx} \\ \sigma_{yx} & \sigma_{x}^{2} \end{bmatrix}$. Ie: the errors are correlated with each other.

Then there is the structural model which does allow for contemporaneous feedback which looks like 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} y_{t} \\ x_{t} \end{bmatrix}  =  \begin{bmatrix} d_{1,0} \\ d_{2,0} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a_{12,0} \\ a_{21,0} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_{t} \\ x_{t}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} a_{11,1} & a_{12,1} \\ a_{21,1} & a_{22,1} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_{t-1} \\ x_{t-1} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \nu_{y,t} \\ \nu_{x,t} \end{bmatrix}
$$
which has covariance matrix $\Sigma_{\nu} = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{y}^{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_{x}^{2} \end{bmatrix}$.

So why are the errors correlated with each other in the reduced form, but independent in the structural form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why are errors correlated in the reduced-form VAR?**
If the error covariance matrix were restricted to be diagonal in the reduced form, the model would be too restrictive to adequately represent most of real-world time series. You could specify such a restricted model, but the assumption of diagonal covariance matrix would often be violated in practice.

**Why are errors uncorrelated in the structural VAR?**
Structural VAR with contemporaneous effects and uncorrelated errors is another representation of the same reduced-form VAR model. For convenience of interpretation, the structural representation is defined by absence of error correlation. Other representations with contemporaneous effects but correlated errors are possible but are less interesting.

Comment: It has been a while since I pondered upon questions of this type and I do not have a definite answer. This is just an attempt I wished to share.